# I need to display an alert message when the last date matches

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. I have a table with fields like `tax`,`start_date` and `end_date`. i retrieve the start and end date from the table. When the date is equal to the end date i need to alert the user that this is the final day so change your settings. i am new to codeigniter so i do not have much idea about it. for example my `start_date is 20/2/2015` and `end_date is 20/5/2015`, i need to get an alert message on `20/5/2015`. my table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `service_taxdate` (
      `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `tax` int(20) NOT NULL,
      `start_date` date NOT NULL,
      `end_date` date NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Have you read the docs about [CodeIgniter's ActiveRecord](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) ?  If not, start by doing this : it's very similar to an SQL query, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the 3 files MVC

the controller:

my_controller.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class my_controller extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model("my_model");
        $data["result"] = $this->my_model->date_verification();
        $this->load->view('my_view',$data);
    }
}
```

the model:

my_model.php

```
<?php
class my_model extends CI_Model
{
        public function date_verification()
        {
            $qry_str = "SELECT *
            FROM `service_taxdate`
            WHERE
            service_taxdate.start_date = service_taxdate.end_date";
            $q = $this->db->query($qry_str);
            return $q->result();            
        }
}
?>
```

the view:

my_view.php

```
<?php 
// html headers ...etc
foreach($result as $row)
{
echo "the id: ".$row->id ." has the same start and finish date ".$row->start_date."<br>" ;
}
```

this code is working with your  table